# Caesar encryption and decryption

Tags: swift, caesar-cipher

For a small project, I had to implement Caesar encryption in Swift(4). I'm mainly looking for performance optimizations.

This whole code should be copy and pasteable in a playground and is functioning as expected as far as I can see.

```
import Foundation

let caesarNumber:Int = 7;

let alphabet_array:[Character] = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]

func encode(inputString: String) -> String {
   var resultString:String = ""

   for char in inputString {
       for i in 0...(alphabet_array.count-1) {
           if (char == alphabet_array[i]) {
               if (i + caesarNumber < alphabet_array.count-1) {
                   resultString.append(alphabet_array[i+caesarNumber])
               }
               else {
                   let subscripture:Int = (i+caesarNumber)%alphabet_array.count
                   resultString.append(alphabet_array[subscripture])
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return resultString
}

func decode(inputString: String) -> String {
   var resultString:String = ""

   for char in inputString {
       for i in 0...(alphabet_array.count-1) {
           if (char == alphabet_array[i]) {
               if (i - caesarNumber >= 0) {
                   resultString.append(alphabet_array[i-caesarNumber])
               }
               else {                         
                   resultString.append(
                      alphabet_array[alphabet_array.count+(i-caesarNumber)])
               }
           }
       }
   }
   return resultString
}

   let encodedString = encode(inputString: "zacharias")
   let decodeString = decode(inputString: encodedString);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Naming

According to the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/), variable names are lower camel case (not `alphabet_array`),
and types should not be part of the variable name (not `caesarNumber`, `inputString`, `resultString`).

It is also clear that the first (and only) argument of `encode()` and `decode()` 
is the input string, here we can omit the argument label:

```
func encode(_ input: String) -> String
```

which is then called as

```
let encodedString = encode("zacharias")
```

#### Improving the API

The current API has two drawbacks:

- It uses the global variable `caesarNumber` to pass information to the 
  functions.
- The function names (“encode”, “decode”) are too common, they to not tell
  what the function actually does.

Here are two alternative suggestions:

1. Make the function names more specific, and pass the shift amount as an
   additional argument.

You can also define a default parameter value for the shift amount.

```
func caesarEncode(_ input: String, shiftBy: Int = 7) -> String 
func caesarDecode(_ input: String, shiftBy: Int = 7) -> String
```

2. Define a *cipher type* with parameters, and encode/decode methods.

That would allow to substitute the Caesar cipher by other methods easily.

```
struct CaesarCipher {
    let shiftAmount: Int

    init(shiftAmount: Int = 7) {
        self.shiftAmount = shiftAmount
    }

    func encode(_ input: String) -> String { ... }
    func decode(_ input: String) -> String { ... }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let rot13 = CaesarCipher(shiftAmount: 13)
let encrypted = rot13.encode("Hello World")
```

I'll stick with the first API for the remainder of this review.

#### Simplify the code

The alphabet can be initialized simply with

```
let alphabet: [Character] = Array("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

because a `String` is a sequence of its `Character`s. Locating a character
in the array can be done with

```
if let idx = alphabet.index(of: char) { ... }
```

instead of a loop. The test for

```
 if (i + caesarNumber < alphabet_array.count-1)
```

is not needed, because the “else case” (with the modulo arithmetic) works actually in both cases, with or without wrap-around.

Summarizing the above suggestions so far, we have for the encoding method:

```
func caesarEncode(_ input: String, shiftBy: Int = 7) -> String {
    var result: String = ""
    for char in input {
        if let idx = alphabet.index(of: char) {
            let newIdx = (idx + shiftBy) % alphabet.count
            result.append(alphabet[newIdx])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Decoding is the same as encoding, only with a shift in the opposite direction.
If we modify the encoding method slightly to work with negative shift amounts then it can be used for the decoding as well:

```
func caesarEncode(_ input: String, shiftBy: Int = 7) -> String {
    var result: String = ""
    for char in input {
        if let idx = alphabet.index(of: char) {
            var newIdx = (idx + shiftBy) % alphabet.count
            if newIdx < 0 { newIdx += alphabet.count }
            result.append(alphabet[newIdx])
        }
    }
    return result
}

func caesarDecode(_ input: String, shiftBy: Int = 7) -> String {
    return caesarEncode(input, shiftBy: -shiftBy)
}
```

#### Improve the performance

For optimal performance on really long strings you can operate on the
UTF-16 view instead, that allows to determine the offset within the alphabet with pure integer arithmetic instead of the array lookup.

Enumerating the UTF-16 view also *seems* to be faster than enumerating
the characters (which represent extended grapheme clusters).

A possible implementation could look like this:

```
func caesarEncode(_ input: String, shiftBy: Int = 7) -> String {
    let letterA = Int("a".utf16.first!)
    let letterZ = Int("z".utf16.first!)
    let letterCount = letterZ - letterA + 1

    var result = [UInt16]()
    result.reserveCapacity(input.utf16.count)

    for char in input.utf16 {
        let value = Int(char)
        switch value {
        case letterA...letterZ:
            let offset = value - letterA
            var newOffset = (offset + shiftBy) % letterCount
            if newOffset < 0 { newOffset += letterCount }
            result.append(UInt16(letterA + newOffset))
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    return String(utf16CodeUnits: &result, count: result.count)
}
```

On my computer this was faster than the previous method (3 milliseconds
instead of 11 milliseconds for a string with 100,000 characters).

For shorter strings that probably won't matter, and you can choose what you
feel more familiar with.